# Trying Save and Copy Website, can't replicate yellow textbox

Tags: html, google-chrome, textbox, web, webkit

I'm trying to save and copy a website trough chrome.

Everything works correctly except for the fact that I can't replicate the Yellow color of the login textboxes.

They are yellow before you click them and write something. Once you start writing, they become white.

As you can see, there's this portion of code that I don't know where to add. I've been struggling for the past 2 hours to solve this, and any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

[Here's the Immage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWAFa.png)

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to style anything. It's Chrome that add this color if you autofill the input. If you still wanna override the default style, use this selector:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Keep in mind that this only apply in webkit browser(Chrome and Safari). You can read more with this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill

Comment: Thank you for your reply! May I ask where should I write it? Because I found it before but I didn't manage to find where I should have added that text.

Comment: Now I understand, It's something related to autocomplete.

It seems like the website has already set autocomplete and fills the form as shown in the picture.

(I didn't click anything, it loads up like that) and I can't find it on the html code.

How could I emulate the same thing? Thank you again!

Comment: Google chrome and Safari emulate this by default when you autofill an input. If you want to override default style, you need to use the pseudo selector :-webkit-autofill like it is written in my answer. Here's another exemple:

    #input-id:-webkit-autofill { your code }

Keep in mind that it is only available in recent Chrome and Safari. So most of your Css won't appear in other and/or older browser. May you accept my answer with the check please? Thank you.